# One local git repo, branches in folders

Tags: git

I've got a GitHub repo that's used as a base for several projects. I keep track of these **projects in seperate branches** on the repo. This enables me to reuse the common parts between the projects, and easily merge over fixes between projects.

In practice, this looks like:

```
 ----------       ---------
 | Remote |       | Local |
 ----------       ---------

  master
  projectA   =>  C:\Projects\ProjectA
  projectB   =>  C:\Projects\ProjectB
```

This setup is working pretty well with me, and for the most part, I'm satisfied. There's one thing that has been bothering me for a while though: I'm duplicating the **full local repo for every project** that I have, while I'm actually only interested in a specific branch for that project.

So if my repo grows to say 1GB for 10 projects, I'll be using 10GB for 1GB worth of code.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to setup my local Git repo in such a way that I would **get rid of this redundancy**?

*Edit:*
The requirement is that these projects have to co-exist simultaneously. I know I could be switching branches, but these projects use npm/bower/gulp, which I would then have to run on every switch. This does not fit my flow and it would become a burden doing quick-fixes on any branch.

*Edit2:*
Some remark on code duplication: the repo contains a WordPress template, which means you inherently end up with a mix of functionality and design. So, the design (html, css, images, scripts) is something that varies between these projects, but the base framework is shared and most of the time remains untouched.

So in theory, I could split the repo into a static and a dynamic part, but if I would have to go there, I don't think the game is worth the candle.

Comment: What do you mean? Don't you have one main branch and then the other branches are created from this one? If that is the case there is duplication of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On local repository can have multiple work trees, so you can check out the same repository (with a single object database) into multiple work trees, every work tree having its own branch it acts on.

Traditionally, you would do this using the [`--work-tree` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) of Git. This can become a bit tedious if you actually want to work with those work trees though.

But [`git-worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) to the rescue! This is a new command with Git 2.5 that allows you to create multiple *managed* work trees, so each one acts on its own while sharing the same local repository. GitHub wrote a good [introduction](https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows) on the command.

The other option you would have is having one local repository, and then multiple clones of that local repository. Since you can clone locally while using symlinks, you could also share the same object database.

And of course, if you actually have multiple *separate* projects then you should consider creating multiple *separate* repositories. If you have shared content, then identify that content and extract it into a common repository which you utilize in each project.

Comment: It looks like git-worktree was designed to exactly alleviate the kind of issue I've got: the need to simultaneously address different versions of your repo. I just *knew* I would get an answer here :D

Answer (score 1):

You have discovered the monorepo - welcome to its power!

Many IT companies use (or aspire to use) a single repo to hold all their code, a setup commonly called a monorepo. [There is a lot of utility in monolithic source control](http://danluu.com/monorepo/), as you have already found.

In my opinion syncing the entire project is a small price to pay. In fact, I don't really see a reason to silo projects in a branch - they should be broken into modules instead. If you are putting them in branches to speed up build times or other tooling issues, there are a bunch of build system specifically designed to handle monorepos (Bazel, Buck, Pantsbuild, at least).

Disk storage is cheap and the download happens once and then is nothing but top-offs from there. That is a small price and probably not worth optimizing against.  My advice is to not worry about the duplication until it becomes an actual problem - it probably never will : )

Answer (score 0):

> So if my repo grows to say 1GB for 10 projects, I'll be using 10GB for 1GB worth of code.

It's highly unlikely a code repo will reach 1GB. For example, the repository for Ruby all the way back to 1998 is only 177 megs.

Where you might get into trouble is if you commit large media files like images, audio, and video. These will rapidly bloat the repository size. To avoid this, use [Git Large File Storage aka git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/). This allows you to store large files in git without bloating the repository.

> Does anyone have a suggestion on how to setup my local Git repo in such a way that I would get rid of this redundancy?

Instead of having each branch checked out individually, get used to switching between branches.

Sometimes you might want to switch but you have uncommitted changes you're not ready to commit.  You can make use of [Git's stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) to squirrel away that unfinished work.

Alternatively, commit the unfinished work, do what you need in the other branch, and when you come back use `git commit --amend` to add to the partial commit.

Answer (score -1):

You can try cloning only the specific branch you want using

```
git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch <folder>
```

Comment: This is unlikely to save much space as each branch will require the full `master` history.

Comment: oh, yes your right what does the main branch contain? if it contains all projects there is duplication of your code

Comment: That was my assumption. If they're unrelated they don't belong in the same repository.